# Как вывести на экран поле объекта из списка массивов

Tags: java, arraylist

Есть такая структура: список массивов объектов (`ArrayList<Word[]> result`).

Сам класс объектов определен следующим образом:

```
public static class Word {
    int ind;
    String word;
    String role;
    int parent;
    String synrole;
}
```

Главная проблема заключается в том, что я не могу пробиться к полям объектов в этой сложной структуре.
Где-то читала, что спасает обращение `result.get(0).word`. В моем случае необходим еще один уровень, но компилятор ругается на запись `result.get(0).get(0).word`.

Как добраться до полей объектов в подобной структуре?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как `result.get(0)` возвращает массив (`Word[]`), то к элементу массива нужно обращаться с помощью `[index]`:

```
result.get(0)[0].word
```

Comment: Гениально) Спасибо за быстрый ответ!

Comment: @RivierraBlackross на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как правильный (галочка слева от ответа).