# Вывод ссылки вместо содержимого в стеке

Tags: java

проблема состоит в том, что при выводе моей персоны выдается, как я понимаю, ссылка на этот экземпляр класса персон.

```
public class StackMas { // реализация самого стека

Person[] stack;
int top;
int sizeStack;

public StackMas(int sizeStack) {
    this.sizeStack = sizeStack;
    stack = new Person[sizeStack];
    top = -1;
}
private void isUniqPerson(Person[] stack, Person addPerson){
    if(addPerson == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person equal null!");
    }
        for (int i = 0; i < stack.length; i++) {
            if(addPerson.equals(stack[i])){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("person already add in stack persons!!!");
            }
        }
    }

void push(Person person){
    if (person == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person equal null!");
    }
        if (stack.length <= sizeStack){
            isUniqPerson(stack, person);
            stack[++top] = person;
        }
}
Person peek(){
    if (top == -1)
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    return stack[top];
}
Person pop(){
        return stack[top--];
}
boolean isEmpty(){
    return (top==-1);
}
```

}

```
public class Person { // создание персоны
String firstName;
String lastName;
int age;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}
```

}

```
public class TestStack { // тест моего стека и создание персоны
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackMas stack = new StackMas(5);

    Person personMax = new Person("Maksim", "Shesterkin", 18);
    Person personAndrey = new Person("Andrey", "Shesterkin", 24);
    Person personAndrew = new Person("Andrey", "Shesterkin", 24);

    stack.push(personMax);
    System.out.println(personMax);
    System.out.print("Стек: ");
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Person value = stack.pop();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: проблема в том, что непонятно, что у вас выводится, что вам хочется, чтобы выводилось, и неизвестно, какая часть кода за это отвечает.

Comment: данные которые содержатся в personMax, personAndrey, personAndrew.

Comment: на данный момент вывод имеется в таком виде: Person@2ff5659e
я хочу, чтобы выводились данные которые содержатся в personMax, personAndrey, personAndrew

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629925/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При запросе к БД, получаю какую-то ерунду вместо контента](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247342/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%ba-%d0%91%d0%94-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить метод toString() в вашем классе Person. Тогда при выводе его в println будет выводиться не ссылка, а та строка, которую вы определите. По умолчанию унаследованный от Object метод возвращает ссылку, что вы и видите.

Comment: public String toString()
    {
        return firstName+ " " + lastName+ " " + age;
    }

Comment: большое спасибо)